# Magento 2 Authorize.net billing address validation

Tags: magento2, checkout, order-status, billing-address, authorize.net

Currently in Magento 2, Authorize.Net validates the billing address after creating the order. If the billing address is wrong then it converts the order status to cancel.

I have found one link about it [Magento 2 - Authorize.net - Transacation fails - Order created with Cancel Status](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187388/magento-2-authorize-net-transacation-fails-order-created-with-cancel-statu)

In that post, he has mentioned about a third-party Authorize.Net payment method, but I did not find any so far which validates the billing address before an order is created.

If anyone knows an extension or tutorial to verify the billing address with Authorize.Net before an order is placed then can you please share it with me?

Comment: I just launched an M2 website using Authorize.net and realized the same flaw.  Did you find a fix for this?  We've got as many cancelled orders as we do actual ones, this is a terrible solution.

Comment: Actually there is a Address Validation Service (AVS) in authorize.net. As much as our AVS settings will be restricted as much are chances to get the address validation error while checkout. What is AVS : https://account.authorize.net/help/Account/Settings/Security_Settings/Fraud_Settings/Address_Verification_System_(AVS).htm . I hope it will help you.